# Excel number format: scale number by ten thousand or hundred thousand

Tags: excel, number-formatting

In Excel, is there a way to display ten thousand or hundred thousand as one?

A comma at the end of a number format scales the number by one thousand. Two thousand with a number format of "#," will appear as "2".

Is there a way to have "20,000" or "200,000" appear as "2"? What is the number format to do so?

Answer (score 1):

In the MSExcel spreadsheet, Right Click on the cell. Then from properties
click on Format Cells -> Click on Tab “Number" -> "Custom"

Now, enter following text in the "Type" Box.

```
0"."0,
```

That should work.

Comment: Wow! That works for 20,000. What about 200,000? Anyway to make it appeared as 2?

Comment: Oh! I just found out that '0"."00,' works for 200,000 to make it appeared as 2. Would you explain how these work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make it to that format as `200,000` is a number already which you want to make it to `2` which is again a number unless you convert it to text and manipulate it,

Try the formula,

`=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""))`

This removes all the `0` from the number. But this works only for trailing zeroes and numbers such like `200001` would give unexpected results. But that would be out of scope for this question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to *change* the value. I want to change how the value appears. Using a number format of "#,", two thousand appears as 2; using a number format of "#,,", two million appears as 2. In both cases, the underlying value doesn't change. Even though 2 appears in the cell, it is still 2,000 or 2,000,000 in the address bar, which shows the real value of the cell. This way, math still works. If the value is changed by a formula, math will not work and that screws up everything.

Comment: @yky unfortunately there is no way to do that

Comment: Using a number format of #"."#####, 2,000,000 is displayed as 20.00000. This is quite close to what I want, if only the trailing zeros can be hidden. Many web sites say number format can display numbers in any way people want. I guess not for this one.

Comment: @yky Yes we may be able to change the format, but the trailing zeroes cant be reduced i guess